Why won't my LinkedList import correctly in Eclipse?
I am learning how to use LinkedList in java and can't seem to get the import to work. I keep getting the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    LinkedList cannot be resolved to a type
    LinkedList cannot be resolved to a type
    LinkedList cannot be resolved to a type

    at StacksQLLExample.main(StacksQLLExample.java:23)

My code:
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class StacksQLLExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        s.push(1);
        s.push(5);
        s.push(52);
        s.push(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(s);
        while (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("peek: "+ s.peek());
            //System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println("pop: "+ s.pop());
        }

        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        q.add(1);
        q.add(5);
        q.add(52);
        q.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        System.out.println(q);
        while (!s.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("peek: "+ q.peek());
            System.out.println("delete: "+ q.remove()) ;
        }
        System.out.println();

        LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>();
        ll.addFirst("D");
        ll.addLast("H");
        ll.add("R"); // same as addLast
        ll.addLast("T");

        System.out.println(ll);
        ListIterator<String> iter = ll.listIterator(); // puts iter at the beginning of the list
        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            String str = iter.next(); // returns what is to the left of the iter
            str += str;
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        if (iter.hasNext()) iter.next(); // iter is at the end of the list
        iter = ll.listIterator(); // back to the beginning

        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            String str = iter.next();

            if (str.equals("D"))
            {
                iter.add("J");
            }

        }
        System.out.println(ll);
        iter.remove();
        System.out.println(ll);
        iter.add("K");
        System.out.println(ll);
        // This creates an error because the iter never moved over with the other element
        // You also can't remove what you just added
        // iter.remove();
        // System.out.println(iter); // prints a memory reference
    }
}

I switched to the IntelliJ IDEA IDE and it works there, but in Eclipse nothing seems to work.

Works on my machine. {tm} Maybe mention java and eclipse versions.

Does your project's Java Build Path include a JRE System Library so that it can find that class? One listed on your Installed JREs preference page and still valid on-disk? What messages are in the Problems view about your project? It should be visible by default in the Java Perspective.

It magically fixed by itself after about 2 days. So peculiar. Thank you for all of your suggestions.
